# ¿Por que el compilador de Visual C++ lanza errores incluso en las bibliotecas Standar de C++?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

Desarrolle un `UserControl` en C# y funciona muy bien, solo por un tema estético, queriendo lograr que dibuje una linea superpuesta sobre múltiples controles contenidos por mi propio control o por controles adyacentes, solución que no encontré en C# y que incluí en una [Pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375182/como-dibujar-lineas-superpuesta-sobre-multiples-controles) , pero que no ha tenido respuesta aun. Después de mucho investigar, he logrado dibujar lineas que se superponen sobre cualquier control, incluso sobre otras ventanas el escritorio, la barra de tareas de windows, en fin sobre toda la pantalla, pero solo lo he logrado hacerlo en C++, para ello es necesario usar `#include "Windows.h"`.

Resulta que cuando he querido convertir mi `UserControl` en C# a C++, en el siguiente archivo, cuando he incluido la linea indicada y al compilar aunque está incompleto, me ha generado nada menos que 53 errores, pero lo más asombroso es que ninguno de los 54 errores, son en lineas de código escritas por mi, si no en lineas de código correspondientes a:

> `oleid.h`, error C2872: 'IDataObject' : ambiguous symbol C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\objidl.h;
>
> `servprov.h`, error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous
> symbol    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio
> 8\vc\platformsdk\include\servprov.h;
>
> `urlmon.h` error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous
> symbol    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\urlmon.h;

Ninguno de esos errores es en los archivos escritos por mi, todos errores en archivos de las biblioteacas standars de visual C++, que las instala el propio visual studio y no creo que contengan errores, no he encontrado la explicación de por que sucede esto, me ha sucedido en Visual studio 2005 y en visual studio 2017, que son los que he usado.

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Buton_Contenedor.h"
#include "ERRG_PanelColapsableControl.h";
#include "resource.h"
#include "Windows.h" //Esta es la linea que incluí y generó todos lo errores
Buton_Contenedor::Buton_Contenedor(void)
{

}

Buton_Contenedor::Buton_Contenedor(ToolStripButton^ bottonComando, System::Drawing::Image^ ImageExpand, 
            System::Drawing::Image^ ImageCollapse,
            Control^ Contenedor)
        {
            this->butonComand = bottonComando;
            this->contenedor = Contenedor;
            this->imageExpand = ImageExpand;
            this->imageCollapse = ImageCollapse;
        }
Buton_Contenedor::Buton_Contenedor(ToolStripButton^ bottonComando, Control^ Contenedor)
        {
            this->butonComand = bottonComando;
            this->contenedor = Contenedor;
        }

Buton_Contenedor::Buton_Contenedor(ToolStripButton^ bottonComando,
            Control^ Contenedor, System::Windows::Forms::TabAlignment alineacion)
        {
            this->butonComand = bottonComando;
            this->contenedor = Contenedor;

            HICON hMyIcon = LoadIcon (hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDB_BITMAP1));
        }
```

EDICIÓN: Realice la prueba de comentar la linea `//#include "Windows.h"`, y compile el proyecto con resultado cero error (Rebuild All succeeded), lo descomenté de nuevo y lo compilé y de nuevo generó los 53 errores; es decir incluir esa linea es la que genera los errores, algo que en teoría según la documentación, no veo por que deba ocurrir.

Comment: No es C++, es C++/CLI, un lenguaje totalmente diferente de C++. Ver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911907/windows-forms-application-lots-of-ambiguous-symbols

Comment: @n.m.ןoṵɐdsǝᴉɯɐןƃǝɹɹɐ Te agradezco, todavía no he podido probar la solución, pero se que por ahí anda el tema, se que tendré que hacer un análisis más profundo de como organizar mi proyecto, es un paradigma muy diferente a lo que estoy acostumbrado a hacer en C#.

Answer (score 0):

Solo cambiar el orden del encabezado del archivo  eliminó todos lo errores, a continuación como estaba en el archivo que provocó los errores.

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Buton_Contenedor.h"
#include "ERRG_PanelColapsableControl.h";
#include "resource.h"
#include "Windows.h" //Esta es la linea que incluí y generó todos lo errores
```

A continuación el orden como lo coloqué, lo que al compilar eliminó todos los errores

```
#include "Windows.h" //Moví esta linea al primer orden.
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Buton_Contenedor.h"
#include "ERRG_PanelColapsableControl.h";
#include "resource.h"
```

Con ese solo cambio, cambiando el orden, se eliminaron todos lo errores.

Comment: Esto responde a *¿cómo solucionar el problema?*, pero la pregunta es un *¿por qué?* Considera añadir una explicación lógica al *¿por qué el error se producía en primera instancias?* Saludos

Comment: @Gabitohh Lo cierto es que ese simple cambio solucionó el problema, String Manolo, me hiso un comentario en donde me dijo "los logs suelen estar ordenados.", eso me sugirió cambiar el orden y todos los errores desaparecieron, pero la explicación de por que ocurrían los errores en la primera forma y al cambiar el orden desaparecieron, esa explicación no la tengo, confieso que no tengo suficientes conocimiento de C++, como para interpretar la causa de por que ocurre esto.Te agradecería que si tienes conocimiento de por que ocurren estas cosas, lo explicaras.

Comment: Se ve que la biblioteca `StdAfx.h` depende de `Windows.h`, o que ambas hacen referencia al mismo espacio de nombres. Además, parece que `StdAfx.h` utiliza hace un `using namespace` de un espacio de nombres que será definido después.

Comment: La [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2872) dice lo siguiente: _Specify a using directive only after all your header files are specified with #include_. En español: **Especifique la directiva using solo después de que todos los ficheros de cabecera hayan sido incluidos**.

Comment: @EequiisVásquez Gracias por tu comentario, son muy útiles todos lo comentarios recibidos.