# ¿Pueden las bibliotecas estándar de C++ entrar en conflicto entre sí, o con las bibliotecas de .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

Sé que es práctica de este sitio exigir que se escriba código de lo que se ha intentado hacer. El código que he escrito está incluido en la [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379924/por-que-el-compilador-de-visual-c-lanza-errores-incluso-en-las-bibliotecas-st), que ya planteé con anterioridad. Esta es solo una nueva expresión de la pregunta.

**¿Existe alguna forma en que las bibliotecas estándar de C++ entren en conflicto entre sí, o que entren en conflicto con las bibliotecas de .NET Framework?**

Answer (score 0):

No si está bien hecha, para eso se usan los scope y los namespace.
Yo puedo hacer 20 librerías y en ellas todas tener un cout distinto. Incluirlas y usar los 21 cout distintos en el mismo programa sin problemas. Véase:

```
std::cout << "hola" << std::endl;
manolo::cout << "que" << manolo::endl;
utils::cout("tal?", "br");
...
```

Comment: Pero resulta que en mi caso después de tener un proyecto que al ser compilado no da un solo error y solo después de incluir la siguiente linea `#include "Windows.h"` genera 53 errores ninguno de ellos en lineas de código escritas por mi, si no en las bibliotecas standars de visual C++, es eso lo que no acabo de entender, dejé el enlace de anterior pregunta `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379924/por-que-el-compilador-de-visual-c-lanza-errores-incluso-en-las-bibliotecas-st`

Comment: No tiene que ver con las libs y el scope. Y es normal que en los logs del código se incluyan funciones que sí usas aunque no programaras tú. Normalmente son llamadas desencadenadas por tu código. Y los logs suelen estar ordenados. A menos que los incluyas todos es totalmente imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Encontré una solución, solo bastó cambiar el orden de las clausulas `#include` incluí la repuesta  a la pregunta original, solo que no acabo de comprender la causa de por que se producen estos errores, puede ser que como planteas `los logs suelen estar ordenados`fue ese comentario tuyo el que me sugirió hacer los cambios, gracias.